# Video is not auto playing on IOS by using react-player npm

Tags: reactjs, html5-video, react-player

I want to play video when user comes to the page, it is working fine for all the platform except IOS. 
I am using [react-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player) npm. I have tried by passing muted property but doesn't work.

My code looks like this

```
<ReactPlayer playing=true url="video_url" muted loop=true />
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need the `playsinline` attribute for iOS autoplaying in non-fullscreen, as per https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/:

> On iPhone,  elements will now be allowed to play inline, and will not automatically enter fullscreen mode when playback begins.
>  elements without playsinline attributes will continue to require fullscreen mode for playback on iPhone.

`react-player` [supports it as a prop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player#props).

Comment: Worked !! Thanks a lot #Vedran !!

Comment: `playsinline`, it is lowercase.

Answer (score 3):

In the docs `playsinline` seems to be lowercase now.

Answer (score 2):

Note that I is uppercase `playsInline`

```js
// Example #1
<video playsInline />


// Example #2
<Player playsInline attr={someValue}>
```

Answer (score 0):

It need H.264 format and you have to put playsInline in react-player to avoid opening apple video player

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).