# ReactPlayer not auto play in IOS platform

Tags: reactjs, react-player

Video just can auto play with pc or android but with IOS, it do not play
[image for my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4U6x.png)

Comment: Maybe this can solve the link problem. https://stackoverflow.com/q/59177977/12348877